# Old anti sweat mixing valve replacement

Tags: toilet

How to replace my old mixing valve with a new one. Are the dimensions the same for old ones and new ones? How to get the right size?

Comment: The pipe and thread dimensions should be the same.  They come in standard sizes.  To be sure, take the old valve to a hardware/plumbing store, or if you must, a big box store.  A plumbing/hardware store might even have repair kits that might be cheaper.